Ruby on Rails giving error on gem install
Keep getting an error when installing rails on my PC. I know that I have the ruby and sqlite installed but I keep getting stuck on the min2. I ahve installed this on my mac and seemed ok. I also see that I installed alinux on my laptop. But this should be ok.
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libyaml
error: failed to init transaction (unable to lock database)
error: could not lock database: Permission denied
pacman failed with the following output:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Users/xxxxx/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/psych-5.1.2/ext/psych
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... no
yaml.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-source-dir
        --without-libyaml-source-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-dir
        --without-yaml-0.1-dir
        --with-yaml-0.1-include
        --without-yaml-0.1-include=${yaml-0.1-dir}/include
        --with-yaml-0.1-lib
        --without-yaml-0.1-lib=${yaml-0.1-dir}/lib
        --with-yaml-0.1-config
        --without-yaml-0.1-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --without-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include
        --without-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --with-libyaml-lib
        --without-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

Also look to have installed the min and the rubyinstall dev kit.
> sh -lc true
MSYS2 seems to be properly installed
Check msys2-keyring version:
 -> up-to-date
Remove catgets to avoid conflicts while update  ...
> pacman -Rdd catgets libcatgets --noconfirm
error: target not found: catgets
error: target not found: libcatgets
MSYS2 system update (optional) part 1  ...
> pacman -Syu --needed --noconfirm
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 clangarm64                                  454.5 KiB   340 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw32                                     244.2 KiB  83.6 KiB/s 00:03 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw64                                     491.2 KiB   165 KiB/s 00:03 [#######################################] 100%
 ucrt64                                      508.8 KiB   376 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 clang32                                     233.4 KiB   179 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 clang64                                     497.6 KiB   297 KiB/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
 msys                                        486.0 KiB  2.03 MiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
:: Starting core system upgrade...
warning: terminate other MSYS2 programs before proceeding
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (3) msys2-runtime-3.5.3-2  pacman-6.0.2-15  pacman-mirrors-20240504-1

Total Download Size:    8.22 MiB
Total Installed Size:  46.26 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.32 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 pacman-mirrors-20240504-1-any                 3.4 KiB  3.29 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 msys2-runtime-3.5.3-2-x86_64               1868.4 KiB  1630 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 pacman-6.0.2-15-x86_64                        6.4 MiB  4.48 MiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 Total (3/3)                                   8.2 MiB  5.63 MiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) checking keys in keyring                                           [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) checking package integrity                                         [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) loading package files                                              [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) checking for file conflicts                                        [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) checking available disk space                                      [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/3) upgrading msys2-runtime                                            [#######################################] 100%
(2/3) upgrading pacman-mirrors                                           [#######################################] 100%
(3/3) upgrading pacman                                                   [#######################################] 100%
:: To complete this update all MSYS2 processes including this terminal will be closed. Confirm to proceed [Y/n]
MSYS2 system update (optional) succeeded
Kill all running msys2 binaries to avoid error "size of shared memory region changed"
 - killing process 4528: C:\msys64\usr\bin\mintty.exe
 - killing process 21020: C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe
MSYS2 system update (optional) part 2 ...
> pacman -Syu --needed --noconfirm
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 clangarm64 is up to date
 mingw32 is up to date
 mingw64 is up to date
 ucrt64 is up to date
 clang32 is up to date
 clang64 is up to date
 msys is up to date
:: Starting core system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (10) bsdtar-3.7.4-1  libgpg-error-1.49-1  libunistring-1.2-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git-11.0.0.r731.g8fdf7c9b5-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-headers-git-11.0.0.r731.g8fdf7c9b5-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmangle-git-11.0.0.r731.g8fdf7c9b5-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libwinpthread-git-11.0.0.r731.g8fdf7c9b5-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-tools-git-11.0.0.r731.g8fdf7c9b5-1
              mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-winpthreads-git-11.0.0.r731.g8fdf7c9b5-1  nano-8.0-1

Total Download Size:    12.63 MiB
Total Installed Size:  215.58 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        0.69 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
:: Retrieving packages...
 bsdtar-3.7.4-1-x86_64                       329.2 KiB   752 KiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 nano-8.0-1-x86_64                           642.0 KiB  1279 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 libunistring-1.2-1-x86_64                   683.7 KiB   907 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 libgpg-error-1.49-1-x86_64                  189.5 KiB   501 KiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-tools-git-11.0.0...   311.0 KiB   494 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-winpthreads-git-...    40.0 KiB   126 KiB/s 00:00 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libwinpthread-gi...    29.2 KiB  53.4 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmangle-git-11...    22.2 KiB  44.3 KiB/s 00:01 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git-11.0.0.r...     4.4 MiB  1998 KiB/s 00:02 [#######################################] 100%
 mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-headers-git-11.0...     6.1 MiB  1833 KiB/s 00:03 [#######################################] 100%
 Total (10/10)                                12.6 MiB  3.66 MiB/s 00:03 [#######################################] 100%
(10/10) checking keys in keyring                                         [#######################################] 100%
(10/10) checking package integrity                                       [#######################################] 100%
(10/10) loading package files                                            [#######################################] 100%
(10/10) checking for file conflicts                                      [#######################################] 100%
(10/10) checking available disk space                                    [#######################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
( 1/10) upgrading bsdtar                                                 [#######################################] 100%
( 2/10) upgrading libgpg-error                                           [#######################################] 100%
( 3/10) upgrading libunistring                                           [#######################################] 100%
( 4/10) upgrading mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-headers-git                      [#######################################] 100%
( 5/10) upgrading mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-crt-git                          [#######################################] 100%
( 6/10) upgrading mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libmangle-git                    [#######################################] 100%
( 7/10) upgrading mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-libwinpthread-git                [#######################################] 100%
( 8/10) upgrading mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-tools-git                        [#######################################] 100%
( 9/10) upgrading mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-winpthreads-git                  [#######################################] 100%
(10/10) upgrading nano                                                   [#######################################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Updating the info directory file...
MSYS2 system update (optional) succeeded

   1 - MSYS2 base installation
   2 - MSYS2 system update (optional)
   3 - MSYS2 and MINGW development toolchain

Which components shall be installed? If unsure press ENTER [] y

Any help would be appreciated.
